# In PHP we have santize to ensure String is safe. What is the similar thing for Java

Tags: java, php, sqlite, sanitization, sanitize

In PHP we have santize to ensure String is safe. What is the similar thing for Java.
I know PreparedStatement . But it will not help me in my project.
Is there is something that checks only letters are there in String .

```
query = "SELECT  Bill_No,No,Item,Count,Rate,GST,Net,Date,Time,Manager FROM bill WHERE Manager = '"+Manager_str+"';  ";
//This is definitely insecure
```

Comment: Why PreparedStatement does not help?

Comment: Also in PHP using [prepared statements](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) preferably with [PDO](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) or [mysqli](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php) is better idea than just sanitizing incoming data.

Comment: If you know about prepared statements, use them and bind values to parameters in those queries. Trying to build a query string from unknown values at run time is the absolute wrong approach to sql.

Answer (score 0):

The `Character` class has a method `isAlphabetic`, which you may use by looping the characters in your input string.

```java
for(char c : query.toCharArray()) {
    if(!Character.isAlphabetic(c)) {
        return false;
    }
}
return true;
```

If you are using Java 8 or above, you could use streams:

```java
return query.chars().allMatch(Character::isAlphabetic);
```

Comment: While technichally true it is not a good idea to manually sanitize sql input. The next requirement will be that a `Manager` can now contain any character, the dev removes this check and ***boom*** ... sql injection

Comment: @KajHejer That would return `true` if atleast one character is a letter.
It should be `query.chars().allMatch(Character::isAlphabetic)`

Comment: @luk2302, that is true. But my answer was more intended towards "Is there something that checks only letters are there in String" part of the question.

Comment: @GauthamM Thanks for your comment about the bug in my code! I have deleted my comment.

Answer (score 0):

try this.

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
    String str="sadahkk";
    System.out.println("str :"+str +" , isAlphabetsOnly:"+isAlphabetsOnly(str));
    str="";
    System.out.println("str :"+str +" , isAlphabetsOnly:"+isAlphabetsOnly(str));
    str="sada5hkk";
    System.out.println("str :"+str +" , isAlphabetsOnly:"+isAlphabetsOnly(str));
    str="<alert>";
    System.out.println("str :"+str +" , isAlphabetsOnly:"+isAlphabetsOnly(str));
    str="-- sadahkk";
    System.out.println("str :"+str +" , isAlphabetsOnly:"+isAlphabetsOnly(str));
    str="@fgfg";
    System.out.println("str :"+str +" , isAlphabetsOnly:"+isAlphabetsOnly(str));

}
public static boolean isAlphabetsOnly(String str ) {
    return ((!str.equals(""))
            && (str != null)
            && (str.matches("^[a-zA-Z]*$")));
}
```

=======================================================

output as follows

str :sadahkk , isAlphabetsOnly:true

str : , isAlphabetsOnly:false

str :sada5hkk , isAlphabetsOnly:false

str : , isAlphabetsOnly:false

str :-- sadahkk , isAlphabetsOnly:false

str :@fgfg , isAlphabetsOnly:false

Comment: This is good and easy .Thank you.

Comment: @JOYSAMRAJ If useful  please up vote and mark as accepted answer